# How to specify from which Numa node the kernel should boot from?

Tags: 20.04, grub2, kernel, qemu, fedora

I have booted ubuntu os using qemu and assigned two NUMA nodes to it.Each NUMA node 0 has 4cpus and 3GB memory whereas NUMA node 1 has no cpus and 3GB memory. The kernel is booted using NUMA node 0. But, I want the kernel to boot it from NUMA node 1 instead of NUMA node 0. Is there any way that I can boot from NUMA node1? Can we change the Grub file or give some additional kernel line parameters to make it work?

Comment: This question has already been posted on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/749545/how-to-specify-from-which-numa-node-the-kernel-should-boot) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1790331/how-to-specify-from-which-numa-node-the-kernel-should-boot). These sites only allow posting to one site at a time; please choose one and delete the other two questions.

Comment: Ok. I deleted the question from the other two sites. Thanks.